# Filemaker Execute SQL with column name

Tags: filemaker

I think this is a very dumb question but I just can't find how to do it.

I'm using ExecuteSQL in filemaker but I noticed the result text doesn't contain the column name, any idea how I can make the result show column name?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add a text line to your calculation, before calling the `ExecuteSQL()` function, e.g.:

```
"SomeField,AnotherField¶" 
& 
Execute SQL ( "SELECT SomeField, AnotherField FROM YourTable" ; "" ; "" )
```

Note that you can use the `GetFieldName()` function to protect your calculation against fields being renamed.

You can also use a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM FileMaker_Fields WHERE TableName='YourTable'
```

to retrieve ALL field names of a table.